# Create-react-app Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, create-react-app, node-serialport

```
_Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in /project/node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings
```

I am facing above error when I build my react application. My application is created using create-react-app and electronjs. I googled for this issue and the most suggested solutions are related to webpack config which I can not directly modify in create-react-app. I tried those solutions like adding 'target: node' and external config etc by ejecting create react app but that also did not work. Before adding serialport package it was working properly now it looks up for the child_process package into serialport libs. So basially in Serialport libs -> linux-list.js they have written `const childProcess = require('child_process');` this in the beginning and there it could not get child_process module. I am not sure how to resolve this, Can someone help me out in this?